# Python - Webdriver and recaptcha

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello i made a instagram account creator but i have a problem with instagram's recaptcha...

This is what im getting while process:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs9ky.png)

I tried create account on my original chrome browser but i got same problem and i tried create account on my ios device and i created a lot of account with safari without recaptcha solve.

I think problem is not code. problem is chrome.

How i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

See captcha,

> CAPTCHA (Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and
> Humans Apart) is a type of security measure known as
> challenge-response authentication. CAPTCHA helps protect you from spam
> and password decryption by asking you to complete a simple test that
> proves you are human and not a computer trying to break into a
> password protected account.

going on..

> A CAPTCHA test is made up of two simple parts: a randomly generated
> sequence of letters and/or numbers that appear as a distorted image,
> and a text box. To pass a the test and prove your human identity,
> simply type the characters you see in the image into the text box.

so basically one can not get rid off captcha easily.

Having said that, you could take help from your OPS team to set up a captch free environment for automation testing. But I am not sure for website like Instagram, how one can proceed.

Comment: can i use any addition or another thing to block recaptcha? point i don't understand i don't get any recaptcha but im getting recaptcha on chrome browser so would changing my browser work?

Comment: Well you could give it a shot with safari as well or with Firefox, but captcha are not meant for automation